# OSX: Replace character in a text file with "characters+1", "characters+2", "characters+3" etc

Tags: macos, replace, terminal

I have a text file with 16000 ">" characters. I would like to replace them with ">1" for the first one, ">2" for the second one,...">160000". Can this be done in osx?

Comment: I thought that something like this might work: tr , ' ' < file , but I don't know how to add the +1, +2 etc

Comment: You should be able to solve this with `awk`. HTH